# React native TextInput Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IInput'

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to create a TextInput component, that has 3 required parameters, and other should be passed as `...rest`, so i can reuse this components in any shape with any props that TextInput can accept.
I have declared a component and interface accordingly:

```
interface IInput {
  styles: ViewStyle
  name: string
  control: Control
  rest: TextInputProps[]
}

export const Input = (props: IInput): JSX.Element => {
  const { control, name, styles, ...rest }: IInput = props
  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    defaultValue: '',
    name,
  })
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={field.value}
      onChangeText={field.onChange}
      style={styles}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

But when i try to use it

```
<Input
  styles={styles.input}
  name="asd"
  control={control}
  keyboardType="email-address"
/>
```

I get a `Type '{ styles: { width: string; height: number; marginLeft: number; fontSize: number; color: string; }; name: string; control: Control<FieldValues>; keyboardType: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IInput'. Property 'keyboardType' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IInput'.`warning.
How it can be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an easier approach of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
interface IInput extends TextInputProps {
  styles: ViewStyle
  name: string
  control: Control
}

export const Input = (props: IInput): JSX.Element => {
  const { control, name, styles }: IInput = props
  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    defaultValue: '',
    name,
  })
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={field.value}
      onChangeText={field.onChange}
      style={styles}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

```js
<Input
  styles={styles.input}
  name="asd"
  control={control}
  keyboardType="email-address"
/>
```

Comment: Exactly, didn't think about that, thought that the 'rest' props should be typed separately somehow, not just extended, thanks!